# Websocket Server, based on socketo.me not accepting connections from shared internet

Tags: javascript, amazon-ec2, websocket, socket.io

I managed to configure a simple websocket server according to [this](http://socketo.me/docs/push) tutorial in AWS EC2 instance and its working fine.
But only from my home internet connection which has a real IP and told as a dedicated internet line.
I tried with a very simple javascript example code from client side (using a HTML page) and it works perfectly if I use that dedicated internet connection from my PC/Mac. (I used `autobahn.min.js`) above the following script.

```
var conn = new ab.Session('ws://X.X.X.X:8080',
          function() {
              console.log("Connection established!");
               // To Do: Subscribe with client ID
          },
          function() {
              console.warn('Connection closed!');
          },
          {'skipSubprotocolCheck': false}
       );
```

but it fails if I run the same simple file/script from under another shared internet connection such as cellular data or something like that. I get the following error in browser console.

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://X.X.X.X:8080/ws' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT example.com Connection closed!
```

The server is in AWS EC2 instance. Yes, 8080 is enabled under security group. Actually all works fine except client connection goes from some specific types of internet connection based computer.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I don't really have enough information to fully answer the question... but if I were to guess, this sounds like a port forwarding issue. Are you using a public IP address?

Comment: Yes, I am using my EC2's public IP in the place of X.X.X.X but I am surprised that its working if I use dedicated internet line. Can you please tell me if a port forwarding is needed from Public IP to Private IP in server end?

Comment: I don't think so.. I got hung up on the words "shared internet connection" and didn't realize you were talking about amazon's cloud hosting. If you deploy your system locally, does it work as expected?

Comment: Yes, I deployed locally and it works

Comment: Do you have any ELB (Elastic Load Balancing) enabled?

Comment: No. Its a simple war EC2 Ubuntu 14.04 instance.

Comment: I'm afraid that I am unable to help. Even a quick google search only comes back with problems using websockets with SSL or using websockets with ELB. Which both cases don't apply in your situation.